# Custom WordPress loop (with video on home page only)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make a custom WordPress Loop in a child theme so that I can add a video to the background of the home page. I have added the template to the child theme for the page that I need to use.

The problem is that several other pages will be using the same template so I need to customize the loop so that it only shows the video on the front page but still uses the template for the rest of the content.

Here is the custom template with the custom loop that I have so far;

```
    <?php 
get_header(); ?>

<?php if (is_front_page()): ?> 

<div class="fullscreen-bg">
<video loop muted autoplay poster="wp-content/uploads/2016/10/I_Waited_VA_Logo.png" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
    <source src="wp-content/uploads/2016/07/I_Watied_VA_Video_1_Long_01.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="wp-content/uploads/2016/07/I-Watied-VA-Video-1-Long.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?> 

    <div id="your-content">
<?php 
while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();
    the_content();
 endwhile; 
 ?> 
 </div>



<?php
get_footer();
    ?>
```

This shows the video but it does not display properly. It also does not work on the other pages that use the template.

Here is the CSS that I am using in style.css;

```
    @import url("../campaign/style.css");


    /* Full screen video*/
    .fullscreen-bg {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: -100;
    }

    .fullscreen-bg__video {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    @media (max-width: 767px) {
.fullscreen-bg {
    background: url('wp-content/uploads/2016/10/I_Waited_VA_Logo.png') center center / cover no-repeat;
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
    display: none;
}
    }

    #your-content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
   }
```

Comment: Using WP template system, you should do this in a way that the home page template is different than the other page templates.  Also, to detect if it's the home page, use the WP function(s) `is_home()` and / or `is_front_page()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `is_font_page()` to create a conditional statement that will only run your code on the front page.

Like so:

```
<?php
  if( is_front_page() ) {
    // code that will run only on the homepage goes here
  }
?>
```

This is assuming you have setup a static front page in your reading settings. If you haven't you should use `is_home() && is_front_page()` together. Thus creating a condition that will run your code only on the first page of your blog, which `is_home()`.

More on is_front_page() in the codex - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page

As for your video, you shouldn't be wrapping your content inside the video or the video container div. Instead you should be wrapping your content and video separately and positioning them with CSS.

**Markup**

```
<div id="fullscreen-bg">
    <video loop muted autoplay poster="wp-content/uploads/2016/10/I_Waited_VA_Logo.png" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
        <source src="wp-content/uploads/2016/07/I_Watied_VA_Video_1_Long_01.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="wp-content/uploads/2016/07/I-Watied-VA-Video-1-Long.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<div id="your-content">
  <?php 
  while ( have_posts() ) :
      the_post();
      the_content();
  endwhile; 
  ?> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#fullscreen-bg {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;    
    z-index: 0;
}

#your-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: I added my CSS to my original post and I also edited in the changes that you and others suggested. It is set to a static front page but is_front_page() does not seem to be working I also tries is_home() but with no luck. After changing the code the video no longer plays at all however the loop is working fine the_post () and the_content() seem to be firing as they should.

Answer (score 0):

Your posts loop is inside the `<video>` tag, so it's no wonder the poor thing doesn't render properly. Also, as already noted in an other answer, you can use `is_home()` and `is_front_page()` to check where you are on the site and inject the video accordingly.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if (is_home() || is_front_page()): ?>

<div class="fullscreen-bg">
    <video loop muted autoplay poster="wp-content/uploads/2016/10/I_Waited_VA_Logo.png" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
        <source src="wp-content/uploads/2016/07/I_Watied_VA_Video_1_Long_01.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="wp-content/uploads/2016/07/I-Watied-VA-Video-1-Long.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php while (have_posts()): ?>

<?php
    the_post();
    the_content();
?>

<?php endwhile; ?> 

<?php get_footer();?>
```